# nginx always routes to first domain

Tags: nginx, configuration, url-routing

I just had to setup my dev server (ubuntu 22.04 in case it matters) to get the networking adapter to work again; unfortunately forgot to backup my domain configurations.

I have three server blocks, let´s call them domain1, domain2 and pma.
nginx.conf includes sites-enabled.

And no matter what I tried so far, any address that routes to that machine delivers from the first server block. With my "default" config, wether I surf to `domain1.test`, `domain2.test`, or `pma.test`; I always get the contents of domain1.

`default` (pointing to `/var/www`) from the enabled domains has no effect.

pma:

```
server {
     listen       80;
     listen       443 ssl;
     server_name  pma.test www.pma.test;
    ssl_certificate         /etc/nginx/my.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key     /etc/nginx/my.key;
     root         /var/www/phpMyAdmin;

     access_log /var/log/nginx/pma-access.log;
     error_log  /var/log/nginx/pma-error.log error;
     index index.html index.htm index.php;

     location / {
                  try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
     }

     location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi.conf;
    }
}
```

domain1 and domain2 are identical apart from the `server_name` and `root` settings.

- Firewall is off for now.
- `nginx.conf` does include the enabled domains.
- `nginx -T` shows that all blocks are included

Please don´t tell me I have to create different SSL certificates for each domain. ;)

Comment: Use `nginx -T` (uppercase `T`) to view the entire configuration across all included files and ensure that all of your server blocks are present.

Answer (score 0):

Everything works fine now. I wasn´t sure what happened at first, when I noticed I´m on a different browser. Cleared the cache in the other one and: bingo.

Sorry for wasting everybody´s time.